# breeze: creating client-side entities with data coming from third-party service

Tags: breeze

I'm getting data from a third-party service and while I had no issues converting to breeze entities, I have one particular scenario that puzzles me:

the data structure I receive is this one (simplified for the sake of clarity)

{
TotalRecords: 72,
Contractors: [ { name: 'test} , {name: 'test2'}]
}

in my jsonResultAdpater, I have created an `extractResults` method, which returns `data.results.Contractors`.
And in my  `visitNode` method, I can convert objects of the Contactors array to breeze entities.

But I've lost the TotalRecords property on the way....   This should be passed somehow to the controller that initiated the call to the third-party webservice.

How would I do that ?

adapter:

```
 extractResults: function (data) {
            var results = data.results;               
            return results && results.Contractors
        },

        visitNode: function (node, parseContext, nodeContext) {               

            if (node && node.Type === 'ContractorFrameworkDTO') {
                return { entityType: "Freelancer" };
           } 
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your jsonResultsAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

actually it was as simple as filling the inlineCount property in the extractResults method:

`data.inlineCount = results.TotalRecords;`